# How to run a flask python application on https server?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask application and I'm trying to run it on https://127.0.0.1:5000/ server.

I'm using below code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

[image: error_image]

But when I run my program and open the link it says your connection is not private. Is this error related to certificates or can we tackle this from our code?

Comment: Have a look at Miguels article. https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https

Comment: Have in mind that on prod you can't run Flask by itself. If you use gunicorn for Flask, then it might be responsible for handling certs.

Comment: Just click advanced and proceed ;)

Comment: My question is why am I getting this page? and can we do something to avoid it other than clicking advance option. @Ardweaden

Comment: Yes, instead of using `adhoc` context, you can provide a proper SSL certificate - you either create a self signed one or buy a one from a CA.  If you do the former, you clients will have to install it as well, otherwise they will get this error. You should choose the latter if you're making a public website. https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ca-certificates

Answer (score -1):

This is a certificate error.just click advanced and accept the certificate.It happen because you are using unsigned certificate.Flask default server is not suitable for production use.I prefer u to use gunicorn with ngnix if u want to u ssl in proper way.If want to bypass this error just configure ur browser setting to accept the certificate

Answer (score -2):

According to my point of view you have to create a certificate. Further you will have to install pyopenssl as well. Detailed article will be on [the following site](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/running-your-flask-application-over-https).